# Make background image blur but not text

Tags: html, css

I am working on my website and making background the image blurry. But the text on the image is showing blurry too.

```css
.container11 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 18%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-1%, -64%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container11">
 <img src="https://www.swoopanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Group-members.jpg" alt="Snow"/>
 <h1 class="centered1">Centered</h1>
 <div class="centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
</div>
```

I also want to add background-image: linear-gradient css to make image blurry.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, rgba(9,132,227,0.85) 40%, rgba(0,59,177,0.98) 100%);
```

But I stucked in the code and this code is not mobile-friendly. When I checked the website on mobile, the alignment of the text changes.

Comment: In what browser/OS combo are you seeing that the text is blurry? In FF on Windows 10 the text looks fine to me.

Comment: I answered a similar q a while ago (don't know which one it was, but [here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/x9Lwtcnr/) Not sure it's exactly the same q but it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `blur` which has a filter effect to your `<img>` tag.

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```
<img class="blur" src="https://www.swoopanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Group-members.jpg" alt="Snow"/>
```

```css
.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.container11 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-1%, -64%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container11">
  <img class="blur" src="https://www.swoopanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Group-members.jpg" alt="Snow" />
  <h1 class="centered1">Centered</h1>
  <div class="centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
</div>
```

I have updated the second solution that uses the background-blend-mode. However, I do not really understand how blend mode works. Please see the code for the effect that I can do.

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.container11:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(16, 123, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(5, 69, 181, 1) 100%), url("https://www.swoopanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Group-members.jpg"), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(16, 123, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(5, 69, 181, 1) 100%);
  <!-- background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, rgba(9, 132, 227, 0.85) 40%, rgba(0, 59, 177, 0.98) 100%), url("https://www.swoopanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Group-members.jpg");
  -->background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: color, overlay;
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.container11 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-1%, -64%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container11">
  <img class="hidden" src="https://www.swoopanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Group-members.jpg" alt="Snow" />
  <h1 class="centered1">Centered</h1>
  <div class="centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Yus Please see the closes effect that I can do.